# Error running Google App script

Tags: google-apps-script

I created an script in https://script.google.com/

and if I open the script in the browser I get the desire result

However, If I try to included it as part of Google Site, following the steps:

1. Edit Site
2. Insert --> App Script
3. and pasting the URL that works above

I get the following error:  It didn't get me the error before with the same script, so I'm not sure if it is because any type of limitations in the number of scripts I can run or somehting like that

**Sorry, the file you have requested does not exist.
Please check the address and try again.**

thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

this is a very old bug in apps script. to fix, change your url "script.xxxx..." to "sites.xxxx...".